# Programmatically change dataLabel's border with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to change the `dataLabel`'s border style dynamically on `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events. How to accomplish that? Here's my code so far:

```
series: [
{
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function () {
                // TODO: Set border programmatically.
                console.log(this);
            },
            mouseOut: function () {
                // TODO: Clear border.
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/18j3c2yz/ - I want to change border style on mouse over and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution - `this.dataLabel.box` property allows to change the border programmatically. Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mLLr7pLg/